# Not an answer approved as helpful, yet answer still exists

Tags: discussion, answers, flags, not-an-answer, specific-answer

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32022534/616443) as "not an answer" which was approved as helpful, yet the answer remains. The "answer" itself is one sentence which appears to be a question:

> It is assessed correctly the parameter 'action' on the page
>   /devilmaycry/register ?

It has no up or downvotes, no edits, and it's four years old. Why wasn't it deleted or converted to a comment if my flag was approved?

Comment: I think that these flags are approved if they are done in good faith but are wrong. (Don't quote me on it, it's what I'm remembering)

Comment: In this instance the post [was deleted and undeleted by a moderator](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/32022534/timeline) and [the LQP review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24207950) was invalidated. The invalidation, I think, got your flag the "Helpful" state.

Comment: The answer seems to have been deleted again, though since I'm <10k I can't see by whom.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sorry, I had accidentally deleted the post (fat-fingered it in the mobile UI). That auto-marks your flag as helpful.

I can’t then correct the flag response, only undelete the post.

As for the post; while the author clearly has some issues with English, they are trying to say that a specific query parameter used in the AJAX call being wrong could be the issue, with the implication that the problem can be fixed by correcting the parameter. That makes it an attempt at answering. I’ve edited the post to replace the Google Translate English with a better sentence structure.